# Simple Xpath xml

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a table thats

```
 <Actor id="RobertDowneyJr">
 <Name>Robert Downey Jr.</Name>
 <BirthDay>1965-04-04</BirthDay>
 <BirthPlace>Manhattan, New York City, New York, USA</BirthPlace>
 </Actor>
 <Actor id="TerrenceHoward">
 <Name>Terrence Howard</Name>
 <BirthDay>1969-03-11</BirthDay>
 <BirthPlace>Chicago, Illinois, USA</BirthPlace>
 </Actor>
```

And i want to use Xpath to only find actors who's born in chicago, but there's something i do wrong

```
  //Disney/Actors/Actor[@BirthPlace = 'Chicago']/BirthPlace

  //Disney/Actors/Actor[BirthPlace = 'Chicago']
```

I just want it to show every actor that is only born in chicago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
//Disney/Actors/Actor[contains(./BirthPlace,'Chicago')]
```

The full `<BirthPlace>` is `Chicago, Illinois, USA`, not just `Chicago`, so you have to switch from `=` to `contains()`.